# How should I handle setter methods that shoud only be used by the factory class?

Tags: c++, oop

I am using a factory class to produce a number of little classes from memory pools. These little classes are constant once they are returned by the factory.

Currently a typical declaration of one of these little objects goes something like this:

```
class LittleObject
{
public:
    ...//non-getter and setter member functions
    int getMemberVariable1() const;//should be accessible to everyone
    void setMemberVariable1(int newMemberVariable1Value);//should only be accessible to factory class
    ...//more getters and setters
private:
    ...
};
```

So, as you can see the getters and setters are both in the public area. But the only time the values should be set is during the time it is being built by the factory class. Now, I can clearly see one option where I move the setter functions to private access and make the factory a friend of the LittleObject class. I find this option a bit inelegant because it exposes other private member functions to the factory. Private member functions which the factory has no business accessing.

So my question is this: **What is the best method making it so that only the factory class can use the setter functions?**

Comment: Make the factor class a `friend` and it will be able to access them or pass the initial values through the constructor.

Comment: Why do you need a factory class? Is a factory-method not good enough?

Comment: The main reason I use the factory class is because the class holds the memory pools used to allocate the LittleObjects and the memory pools used to allocate the 'micro-arrays' inside the little objects (small arrays with between 2 and 8 long long ints depending on the object).

Comment: Why isn't `getMemberVariable1()` `const`?

Comment: @ChrisDrew It is in the class definitions that I have, I just forgot to add it here as I was typing a 'quasi-class' as an example.

Comment: OK. In which case as long as only the factory deals with non-const LittleObjects only the factory can call the setter.

Comment: Can you afford polymorphism?  I.e could the factory return a (smart) pointer to an abstract base class that only allows read access.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I was avoiding polymorphism in this context as hundreds of billions of these things are created and destroyed and I am trying to make the cost of making/using LittleObjects as low as possible. As for the const part, if I understand you correctly, unfortunately some of the Little objects are used as indices in a b-link-tree and making those constant so they are only modifiable on construction of nodes and pages of the tree would make for a lot of work and rebuilding of nodes and pages of the tree when I needed to make a change.

Comment: You might want to lookup the Attorney-Client and Passkey patterns as a way of only allowing friend access to certain functions but in this case I think it might be overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [`friend class`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class):

```
class LittleObject
{
    friend class LittleObjectFactory;

public:
     int getMemberVariable();

private:
     void setMemberVariable( int value );
};
```

Comment: As I had said in the question, I found this a bit inelegant. This is because it exposes other private member functions to the factory. If there is no other way then that is what I must do. But I had been hoping otherwise.

Comment: This is one of those cases where `friend` strengthens encapsulation  if the factory class _really_ needs to access those functions.

Comment: not sure... is it possible to have an inheritance so that the base class contains all functions necessary for the factory who is only friend of the base, and the other private details are moved to the derived part?

Answer (score 1):

I would really prefer to `friend` the factory, but if you need stronger 
encapsulation, at the expense of elegance, mabe it can be done

```
struct LittleData;

class Factory
{
public:
    void MakeLittle(LittleData&);
};

struct LittleData
{
    int data1;
    float data2;
};

class LittleObject
{
public:
    LittleObject(const LittleObject&) = default;
    LittleObject& operator=(const LittleObject&) = default;

    int GetData1() const { return data.data1; }
    float GetData2() const { return data.data2; }

    static LittleObject MakeOne( Factory& f )
    {
        LittleObject obj;
        f.MakeLittle(obj.data);
        return obj;
    }
private:
    LittleObject();
    LittleData data;
};
```

Looking at what I just wrote... I really prefer `friend`

Comment: Yeah, I think I am going to have to resort to it because, honestly, this method, while it avoids friend, is a bit... messy looking. I had thought that friend made it less elegant, but compared to this it is much preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is ***stencils***.

By that I mean static instances of each `LittleObject` preset to the required configuration so that the factory simply needs to make a copy.

The copy can be made via the copy constructor or, if you don't want to make one of those (and the objects are trivial) then you could use `memcpy()`.

Here is an example using copy constructors:

```
class LittleObject1
{
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    LittleObject1(const LittleObject1& o): a(o.a), b(o.b) {}
    LittleObject1(int a = 0, int b = 0): a(a), b(b) {}

    static LittleObject1 stencil;

    int get_a() const { return a; }
    int get_b() const { return b; }
};

LittleObject1 LittleObject1::stencil(3, 7); // preset values

class LittleObject2
{
    std::string s;

public:
    LittleObject2(const LittleObject2& o): s(o.s) {}
    LittleObject2(const std::string& s = ""): s(s) {}

    static LittleObject2 stencil;

    std::string get_s() const { return s; }
};

LittleObject2 LittleObject2::stencil("hello"); // preset values

class Factory
{
public:

    template<typename Type>
    Type* create() const
    {
        return new Type(Type::stencil); // make a copy of the preset here
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory fact;

    LittleObject1* o1 = fact.create<LittleObject1>();

    std::cout << o1->get_a() << '\n';
    std::cout << o1->get_b() << '\n';

    LittleObject2* o2 = fact.create<LittleObject2>();

    std::cout << o2->get_s() << '\n';
}
```

This would only be useful if the values are preset and don't need calculating at run-time.

Comment: See also the Prototype pattern from GoF.

Comment: This makes a good deal of sense, definately something to remember for the future. Unfortunately the little objects contain pointers into memory allocated by a memory pool so that has to be determined at the time of creation, they're not all identical LittleObjects, merely constant after they have been created / setup.

Answer (score 1):

**Rely on const-correctness**

You say the objects are constant when they are returned by the factory.
In that case why not just return `const` objects:

```
class Factory
{
public: 
   std::unique_ptr<const DynamicLittleObject> createDynamicLittleObject();

   const AutomaticLittleObject createAutomaticLittleObject();

};
```

Then just ensuring to write their functionality in a const-correct way will give the correct access control.

Some might worry about the case the user might cast away the constness, but there's only so much that is worth doing to protect them from themselves.

Comment: I like this idea, but I, among other things, use these objects as keys in a B-Link tree. When I have to reshuffle indices in the nodes of the trees, doesn't that require non-const?

Comment: @JamesMatta That sounds a bit different from what you asked in your question. If it's the "factory" that's doing the shuffling then it can create the objects as non-const so that it can work with them more freely internally.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the factory a static member function of each object. So each object type knows how to create itself. Then you can have some kind of template function to make creating them a little less typing.

**Something a bit like this:**

```
class LittleObject1
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

public:
    virtual ~LittleObject1() {}

    static LittleObject1* create()
    {
        LittleObject1* o = new LittleObject1;
        o->a = 1;
        o->b = 2;
        return o;
    }
};

class LittleObject2
{
    std::string s;

public:
    virtual ~LittleObject2() {}

    static LittleObject2* create()
    {
        LittleObject2* o = new LittleObject2;
        o->s = "hello";
        return o;
    }
};

template<typename Type>
Type* createType(Type*)
{
    return Type::create();
}

int main()
{
    LittleObject1* o1 = createType(o1);
    LittleObject2* o2 = createType(o2);
}
```

Comment: I get what you are saying, and that is a fairly neat trick, certainly something to keep in mind in the fugure. As I said in the comments on the question though, I use the factory to manage the memory pools for both the LittleObjects and the 'micro-arrays' they have pointers to. I do not want to stick a reference to the memory pools in each LittleObject, they stop being quite as little then.

Comment: @JamesMatta I suppose you've already rejected the notion of having a dreaded singleton for your memory pools?

Comment: @JamesMatta Actually I see no reason my `createType()` function can't be a member of your Factory class that manages the thread pools and it could pass the relevant object as a parameter to each `LittleObject`'s static `create()` function.

Comment: That's a bit of code overhead for something that amounts to a default constructor.

Comment: @Galik As to singleton memory pools, there are multiple pools the one used for the LittleObjecth is chosen depending on the size of the 'micro-array' the little object needs. That makes recycling the memory from the pools, very easy. So, in essence, all the memory pools are the same class just with different parameters about how much to dole out from their arrays.